# python pandas with parameter length changing

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do

```
df[(df['col']==50) | (df['col']==150) | etc ..]
```

"etc" is size changing from 1 to many
so I do a loop
result is like

```
str= "(df['col']==50) | (df['col']==150) | (df['col']==100)"
```

then I do this

```
df[str]
```

but this does not work
How can I make it work ?

Comment: This is unclear. The `or` of many boolean series is distinctly different than a string of words representing python code that would be used to calculate boolean series. Perhaps you're looking for [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query)?

Comment: As an aside, do not shadow the build-in `str` by using it as a variable name.

Comment: instead of saving it as a string why don't you just do this `condition = ((df['col']==50) | (df['col']==150) | (df['col']==100))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
list_of_numbers = [50,150]
df[df["col"].isin(list_of_numbers)]
```

Where `list_of_numbers` are the numbers you want to include in the condition. I'm assuming here your condition is always `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `query` to filter a dataframe from a string

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(25, 225, 25)})

l = [50, 100, 150]
q = ' | '.join([f"col == {i}" for i in l])

out = df.query(f)
```

```
>>> q
'col == 50 | col == 100 | col == 150'

>>> out
   col
1   50
3  100
5  150
```